# Multiple numbers per problem + answer line to left

Tags: exam

I have not tried anything yet for my problem because I am not sure what to try. There are 2 parts to my question.

1. I need to create a test where each problem is numbered based on how many points it is. For example, in the picture below, this one problem is worth 3 points. While I could do this manually, it feels like this goes against the reasons for using LaTex to format my document in the first place. (I have not chosen this way of labeling things, so it is not an option to do it a different way.)
2. How do I put the answer line to the left? (for this, I am thinking to do a minipage for each problem but wondering if there is a better solution)

[image: testproblem]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.